# SQL Syntax to Group by Date and Case statement

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

My mysql database resembles the following and am struggling with the proper use of case, group by and order by statements.  The sample dataset:

```
ID     Date          Direction
1      2017-04-01    1
2      2017-04-01    1
3      2017-04-01    -1
4      2017-04-01    1
5      2017-04-01    -1
6      2017-04-01    1
7      2017-04-02    -1
8      2017-04-02    -1
9      2017-04-02    -1
10     2017-04-02    1
11     2017-04-02    -1
12     2017-04-03    -1
```

I am trying to understand the best way to aggregate this table and group by date so that the query returns the following recordset.  The "positive" column below is simply a count of the direction column (above) where direction > 0.  Similarly, the "negative" column is a count of the direction column where direction < 0 like so:

```
DATE         positive      negative   
2017-04-01   4             2
2017-04-02   1             4
2017-04-03   0             1
```

I have tried:

```
 SELECT DATE, 
        CASE
            WHEN direction < 0 THEN 'negative'
            WHEN direction > 0 THEN 'positive'
        END AS updownType, count(*) AS updownCount
        FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-03'
        GROUP BY DATE, updownType
        ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

I've reviewed dozens of SO threads on this topic, but just haven't run across what I am looking for yet.  Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops you just miss it . see below

```
SELECT DATE, 
        count(CASE WHEN direction < 0 THEN '1' END) AS negative,
        Count(CASE WHEN direction > 0 THEN '1' END) AS positive 
        FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-03'
        GROUP BY DATE
        ORDER BY DATE ASC
```